# Extracting overlapping objects in a binary image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am looking for a method to extract each lines in this binary image.

I use opencv libraries with c++.

The method I tried:

```
Step 1: Thinning - resulted in lines with sharp curves when they shouldn't
Step 2: follow the line's path. However, some part of the sample image resulted in 
        thinning where it created intersections that curve to wrong direction.
Step 3: Erode - all other objects outside the objects skeleton/thinning path.
```

I am sure there many more robust method for solving this. Please guide me.

Thank you.

Sample Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use the distance transform. Linearly combine the three versions (L1, L2, C). Then apply a Gauss filter on top of it. Finally do a thresholding.

It will work better than the thinning.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am new in image processing as a whole. What does LInearly combne mean?

Comment: It means that if you have the results in matrices l1, l2, c, you say `Mat result = (l1 + l2 + c)/3.`